# iFrame cookie only being read after page refresh

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, caching, iframe, cookies

I have a .net site that runs in an iFrame. In order to track various things on the page I use a cookie. I'm using a p3p header to ensure IE can read the cookie.
However it doesn't always seem to work. If I follow the steps below I can recreate an issue.

1. Delete all cookies from IE
2. Browse to iFrame containing my pages
3. Cookie is read OK.
4. Close browser
5. Navigate back to iFrame
6. Cookie not read
7. Refresh the page (F5)
8. Cookie is read OK
9. Repeat from step 4. ad infinitum...

Is this a caching issue in the parent page or the iFramed page?
If it is a caching issue how can I ensure IE doesn't cache this specific page and instead reloads the page along with the cookie?

Needless to say this doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox.

Any light that could be shed on this will be much appreciated.

S.

Answer (score 1):

This is a caching issue with the iFrame.  The way to get around it is to add a unique query string parameter to the url in the iFrame.

Something like this will work:

```
<iframe src="http://www.MyAspNetApplication.com?q=<% =DateTime.Now.Ticks %>"></iframe>
```

Where q is the unique query string param.

Comment: This makes perfect sense but it doesn't seem to affect the caching in IE.

Comment: Can you check the source of your page to make sure the src of the iframe is unique for every visit?